# Reset snap refresh time

Tags: snap

None of my Snaps are getting updated as the refresh time for some reason is set to 2025, is there any way to reset this?

```
$ snap refresh --time
timer: 00:00~24:00/4
last: 2025-03-08
next: 2025-03-08
```

Comment: Try setting the `refresh.timer`  https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date

Comment: Usually a `snap refresh` (without the `--time` option) will force the refresh to take place. Does your computer regularly have its internal clock forwarded by several years? 

Comment: @matigo that's the thing I don't know where it got this time from unless it was when I very first installed a new motherboard that hadn't synced the time yet?

Comment: @Terrance unfortunately no luck, it changed the timer but not the last or next:

$ snap refresh --time
timer: mon,tue,wed,thu,fri
last: 2025-03-08
next: 2025-03-10

Comment: Bummer.  I wonder if reinstalling it might help:  `sudo apt install --reinstall snap snapd`

Comment: That didn't fix it but gave me an idea, just do a full purge and reinstall and it fixed it :D thanks!

Comment: Would be interesting to know if there's another fix for this. Purging snap and snapd will also remove any installed snaps, and can be a massive pain to reinstall all of them.

Maybe there is a doc with the default refresh timers, or an easier way to reset the timer back to default?